# How to work with base64 encoded params that include dynamic variables in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, base64

I am working on a performance script in Jmeter that contains a number of http requests. One of the parameters I pass in my request will always be formatted as follows:

{"a":"transition9","ap":"203867"}

Everything about the above remains constant with the exception of "ap". I need to pull "ap" from regular expression extractor, which I can do.
So at the end of the day the above will actually look something like this.

{"a":"transition9","ap":"${regexExtractedValue}"}

Here is the really tricky part. If I can achieve the above, I then need to base64 encode the value, which I know can be done using ${__base64Encode(test string)}. See https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup.

I have tried a number of approaches, which mainly have involved splitting up the hardcoded values and trying to combine them with the dynamic values, but the comma seems to throw it off. An example of something I have tried.

prefix = eyJhIjoidHJhbnNpdGlvbjkiLCJhcCI6Ij
ap = ${__base64Encode(203867"})
Then you would combine the 2 and the value being passed into the param would look something like this

{"stuff":"thing","__Action":"${prefix}${app}","__Scroll":"base64:MA=="}

This yields strange results. Is there a way to get what I need here?

Answer (score 0):

In the parameter value I used this format:
${prefix}${__base64Encode("${post}"})}